# How to use Laplace with this example?

Tags: laplace-transform, control-theory

i am studying the book "Linear Systems" by Kailath and on page 32 I do not unsterstand how this author uses laplace to get from

$$
 \left[ \begin{matrix} \dot x_1 \\ \dot x_2 \end{matrix} \right]
=\left[ \begin{matrix} -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right]
 \left[ \begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{matrix} \right]
+\left[ \begin{matrix} -2 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right]v, ~~~
\left[ \begin{matrix} x_1(0) \\ x_2(0) \end{matrix} \right]
=\left[ \begin{matrix} x_{10} \\ x_{20} \end{matrix} \right]
$$

$\dot x_1 = - x_1 - 2v, ~~~ x_1(0)=x_{10}$ (I do understand this)

to

$ x_1(t)=e^{-t}x_{10}-2e^{-t} * v $ (* denotes convolution)

I cannot find a laplace theorem like http://www.rapidtables.com/math/calculus/laplace_transform.htm that would explain this.

Comment: I tried to solve the first equation, as reference I used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor. $$(11)~ \frac{d}{dt} (x_1 e^{\int_{s0}^{t} P(s) ds}) = 2v e^{\int_{s0}^{t} P(s) ds} \\
(12)~ x_1 e^{\int_s0^t P(s) ds} = \int_{\tau 0}^{t} 2v e^{\int_{s0}^{\tau} P(s) ds} d\tau + x_{10} \\
(13)~ x_1 = e^{-\int_{s0}^{t} P(s) ds} \int_{\tau 0}^{t} 2v e^{\int_{s0}^{\tau} P(s) ds} d\tau + x_{10} e^{-\int_{s0}^{t} P(s) ds} \\
(14)~ x_1 = e^{0} 2v e^0 + x_{10} e^0 =2v +x_{10}$$

Comment: Thanks, I get closer, I do not know how to get to the convolution, $$ \\
(1)~ u(t)(x'_1 + P(t) x_1), ~~~P(t)=1 \\
(2)~ u(t)x'_1 + u(t)P(t)x_1 \\
... \\
(8)~ x'_1 e^{t} + 1 x_1 e^{t} = -2v e^{t} \\
(9)~ x'_1 e^{t} + x_1 e^{t} = \frac{d}{dt} (x_1 e^{t} ) ~~~~ reverse \ product \ rule \\
(10)~ \frac{d}{dt} (x_1 e^{t}) = -2v e^{t} \\
(11)~ x_1 e^{t} = -2v \int e^{t} dt =-2ve^{t} + x_{10} \\
(12)~ x_1 = -2v e^{t-t} + e^{-t}x_{10} = -2v + e^{-t}x_{10} \\
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since convolution in the time domain is just multiplication in the Laplace domain, it is easier to solve this using the Laplace domain.

In general a inhomogeneous linear time invariant differential equation can be written as,

$$
\dot{x}(t) = A\,x(t) + B\,u(t), \tag{1}
$$

with $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times 1}$, $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $\dot{x}$ the time derivative of $x$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $u\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times 1}$. Transforming equation $(1)$ into the Laplace domain yields,

$$
s\,X(s) - x(0) = A\,X(s) + B\,U(s), \tag{2}
$$

with $X(s)=\mathcal{L}\{x(t)\}$ and $U(s)=\mathcal{L}\{u(t)\}$. This can be rewritten to,

$$
X(s) = (s\,I - A)^{-1} x(0) + (s\,I - A)^{-1} B\,U(s). \tag{3}
$$

Similar to $\mathcal{L}^{-1}\! \left\{\frac{1}{s-a}\right\}=e^{a\,t}$ the inverse Laplace transform of $(s\,I - A)^{-1}$ yields a [matrix exponential](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html) $e^{A\,t}$. This mean that  the inverse Laplace transform of equation $(3)$ can be written as,

$$
x(t) = e^{A\,t} x(0) + \mathcal{L}^{-1}\!\left\{\mathcal{L}\{e^{A\,t}\}\,\mathcal{L}\{B\,u(t)\}\right\}. \tag{4}
$$

But as stated in the beginning of my answer, multiplication in the Laplace domain is the same as convolution in the time domain. In your case you have $A=-1$ and $B=-2$. In general when dealing with matrices the order of multiplication matters, since they do not [commute](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CommutingMatrices.html), but in this case we are dealing with scalars, which do commute, so solving for $x_1(t)$ using equation $(4)$ would yield,

$$
x_1(t) = e^{-t} x_{10} - 2\, [e^{-t}\,*\,u(t)](t),
$$

with $[f\,*\,g](t)$ meaning the [convolution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html) between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is a lot easier than what I tried above but do you know how to solve $$ x_1 e^{t} = -2 \int v(t)e^t dt $$

Comment: @autoship solving this not give you the solution for $x_1(t)$, since it does not depend on $x_{10}$.

Comment: If I solve the integral I would (always) have a constant. I thought that $ x_{10} $ could be the constant.

Comment: @autoship You are right. Solving that equation for $x_1(t)$ yields, $$x_1(t)=e^{-t}\,C - 2\int e^{\tau-t} v(\tau)\,d\tau$$ but this is just convolution written in another way.

Comment: With $C$ also containing the integration constant.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually pretty easy to prove if you work only in Laplace domain.
$$\dot{x}_1(t)=-x_1(t)-2v(t)$$
Taking Laplace transform on both sides we get:
$$sX_1(s)-x_{10}=-X_1(s)-2\mathcal{L}(v)$$
$$\Rightarrow X_1(s)=\frac{1}{s+1} x_{10} - \frac{2}{s+1}\mathcal{L}(v)$$
$$\Rightarrow X_1(s) = \mathcal{L}(e^{-t}) - \mathcal{L}(2e^{-1})\mathcal{L}(v)$$
Notice that the last term is a product of two functions in $s-$domain, and so taking inverse Laplace would replace the product with a convolution as follows:
$$x_1(t)=e^{-t}-2e^{-t}*v(t)$$